# If I cancel a technology research, will it keep the technology points spent?

Tags: factorio

Let suppose two researches I want to do : A and B.

I cancel the actual research A to start researching B.

Then, B is finished so I restart A.

**Is the progress of the previous research lost ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you select another technology to research, the progress on the current one is lost.

This is as of version 0.12.

Answer (score 8):

The progress is now saved as of version 0.16